# H2 and FOREIGN KEY

Tags: sql, h2

I ran into a problem:

I was going to create 2 tables in H2. When I tried to create the second table, an error occured:

> column C_TASK not found

Here is the code:

```
CREATE TABLE S_TASK (C_TASK INT PRIMARY KEY, N_TASK VARCHAR(255), POINT_COUNT INT);

CREATE TABLE S_ACHIEVEMENT(C_ACHIEVEMENT INT PRIMARY KEY, N_REWARD VARCHAR(255), PICTURE VARCHAR(255), FOREIGN KEY (C_TASK) REFERENCES S_TASK(C_TASK), EXEC_COUNT INT);
```

Comment: When posting, please change the business context to something simple, obvious, and intuitive. In your context, it is not obvious which table is parent and which is child. Also, actually creating a simple example and running it before posting will often have the nice side-effect of revealing your problem/solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Did Not Define Linking Field

You are defining a relationship (a foreign key) for a column that does not exist in table `S_ACHIEVEMENT`. A foreign key a link between a column on a child table (the "many" table) and a column on the parent table (the "one" table). Your code says you wish to link from a field "C_TASK" on "S_ACHIEVEMENT" but there is no "C_TASK" field on that table.

## Example

Take for example customers (parent table) who have 0 or more invoices (child table), and every invoice must be owned by exactly one customer. Similarly, the invoice table is in turn a parent to the line items table.

[image: diagram of three tables, invoice_ linking to customer_, and line_item_ linking to invoice_]

You would have tables and columns:

- customer_

  - name_
  - phone_
  - uuid_  (primary key)
- invoice_

  - invoice_number_
  - date_of_invoice_
  - uuid_  (primary key)
  - fk_customer_uuid_  (foreign key)
- line_item_

  - item_number_
  - product_sold_
  - cost_
  - uuid_  (primary key)
  - fk_invoice_uuid_  (foreign key)

On the invoice_ table you would define:

```sql
ALTER TABLE invoice_ ADD FOREIGN KEY ( fk_customer_uuid_ ) REFERENCES customer_( uuid_ ) ;
```

and

```sql
ALTER TABLE line_item_ ADD FOREIGN KEY ( fk_invoice_uuid_ ) REFERENCES invoice_( uuid_ ) ;
```

Those columns marked "(foreign key)" is what you forgot to define on your child table.

See this posting, [H2 Alter Table Add Foreign Key](http://razorsql.com/features/h2_add_foreign_key.html), for another example.